# "Reboot or select proper boot device" Error after install Ubuntu on Win 8 Drive

Tags: mbr, uefi

I have a Gateway DX4885 machine that came with a new install of Windows 8. Upon receiving the computer I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04LTS desktop, using the format tool in the Ubuntu install process. After installing it boots into Ubuntu fine, but after a reboot I receive the error message "reboot or select proper boot device". I have done multiple installs in various ways. I have tried the boot-repair tool and it did not do anything. I have also disabled SecureBoot in the BIOS. Does anyone know a work around for this?

Comment: this would be better asked on ubuntu's forum.

Comment: Please post either the URL that Boot Repair gave you or a URL to a pastebin site holding the `RESULTS.txt` file that the  [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) generates. Without this information any answer will be nothing but a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved using a utility called efibootmgr. I had to run this to remove the windows efi boot partitions. I hope this can help someone else avoid the headache I went through trying to solve this issue.